# How to hide a dynamically created EditText box in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to make an attendance plus tasking system. For this, I have used check-boxes and a linear layout. Linear layout is for adding edit-text box dynamically. When a check-box is checked, a new text field is to be visible and when it is unchecked, the text field has to be hidden. I have used part of code something like this:

```
    public void onCheckBoxClicked(View v) {
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
    EditText tv;
    tv = new EditText(this);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
tv.setText(one.getText().toString()+ "'s task today?");
tv.setBackgroundColor(0xff66ff66); // hex color 0xAARRGGBB
tv.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);// in pixels (left, top, right, bottom)

switch (v.getId()) {

case R.id.checkBox1:
if(checked) {
list.addView(tv);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), one.getText().toString() + " is present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

if(!checked) {
 tv.setVisibility(EditText.GONE);   //problem exists here--is not executing
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), one.getText().toString() + " is  absent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                break;
```

Now, I can easily get a edit-text field when I check the box but, on unchecking it, the edit-text field doesn't hide. How can I solve it?

Comment: I have tried it. View doesn't work as well.

Comment: Try to use `checkBox1.isChecked()` instead of  `checked`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are creating new EditText each time some checkBox clicked. You are trying to hide EditText which isn't even shown/added yet. Got it!!

Try making your `EditText tv = new EditText(this);` editText as class variable , create it in onCreate. And then you can hide/show when you need it.

it would look something like below code.

```
EditText tv;
onCreate(.......){
..............

tv = new EditText(this);
..............
}
```

and then use this `tv` in your `onCheckBoxClicked` method instead of creating one in this method.